# Error on rendering show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, show

I am trying to render show action by passing parameters, but the show page is not being rendered when there are no users signed in. This is my controller:

```
class QrCodesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_qr(params[:id])
    if @user.nil?
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my view:

```
This is the qr-code page of <%= @user.fname %> <%= @user.lname%>
```

However, the show page is perfectly rendered when any user is signed in.

The rails server also shows perfectly rendered show action:

```
Started GET "/qr_codes/9M9JZLiemrNdS_g90mZ14w" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-02 18:29:55 +0545
Processing by QrCodesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9M9JZLiemrNdS_g90mZ14w"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."qr" = '9M9JZLiemrNdS_g90mZ14w' LIMIT 1
  Rendered qr_codes/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Web Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "webs".* FROM "webs" WHERE "webs"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 52.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

I am using rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.3p429 along with devise 3.0.0. The User model was not generated by devise.

Please Help.

**EDIT:**
This is the link that triggers the show action:

```
http://localhost:3000/qr_codes/9M9JZLiemrNdS_g90mZ14w
```

Comment: what errors you are getting when user is not logged in and trying to open the show page?

Comment: If it is redirecting to another action, please check is there any before filter action in application controller.

Comment: There are no errors, just empty page.

Comment: @Mohanraj: It remains in the same page, it is not being redirected.

Comment: can you edit your questions for the link from which you are going to the show page?

Comment: @suhs: ok, can you post the log when user not sign in?

Comment: Can you please add a puts statement that prints `@user` before the `if @user.nil?` line?  What is the value when the user is not signed in?

Comment: @Mohanraj: I have already posted it in the question.

Comment: @Powers: This is the output: #<User:0x007f33284fd0a0>

Comment: plz debug @user.fname

Comment: @Debadatt: What do you mean to say by debug @user.fname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @user is equal to  # when you print it, it is clearly not equal to nil and the redirection is not happening. You need to either change the code in find_by_qr to return nil if not found, or determine what other way that that method is using to represent not found, and change your conditional to use that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
@user = User.find_by_qr(params[:id])
if  @user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
  end
else
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: There is no difference. The page is still blank.